# Need help disassembling Qualcomm QDSP6

Tags: ida, disassembly

Im trying to disassemble a qualcomm QDSP6 modem file. According to the ELF header, there should be 26 sections(modem.b00-b25). However after dumping the device, b.16,b.17,b.25 are missing, making the file impossible to open with IDA.

The device is an Alcatel 4060-A. I have full access to the phone's emmc via usb download mode, also tried dumping the same modem partition via ADB. Same result, the partition is missing those 3 sections. Even reading the raw unpacked file in a hex editor, there is no mention of those 3 elf sections

Any suggestions?

Comment: how did you do "dumping the device"? what device? provide more info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the program headers with `readelf -a modem.b00`.
It will show you which sections have a `FileSiz` of zero bytes. These are probably the ones missing.

Then you can put together the original `ELF` file by loading each `modem.bNN` section at the right offset, as indicated by the `Offset` field in the `readelf -a` output.

I don't know which rom you used, i downloaded the one from [xdadev](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/rom-alcatel-ideal-4060a-stock-android-5-t3637885)

unzipped using `unzip`. Then extracted the `modem.img` file using `7z`:

```
7z -omodem x modem.img
```

then in `modem/image` there are the `modem.bNN` files.
of those: b04, b17, b18 and b25  are missing.
When looking at `readelf -a modem.b00`, I can see that those are exactly the ones with `FileSiz == 0`.

```
Type    Offset   VirtAddr PhysAddr FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
NULL    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000374 00000000     00000000    -- b00 ELF header
NULL    00001000 8d500000 8d500000 00001c68 00002000     00001000    -- b01 hashes, signature, certs
INTERP  01c47280 c1cbe280 89cbe280 00000001 00000001 R   00000001    -- b02
LOAD    00003000 c0000000 88000000 00001540 00001540 R E 00001000    -- b03
LOAD    00005000 c0004000 88004000 00000000 00001000 RW  00001000    -- 
LOAD    00005000 c0008000 88008000 0002c160 0002c160 RW  00001000    -- b05
LOAD    00032000 c0038000 88038000 0005e340 0005e340 RW  00001000    -- b06
LOAD    00091000 c00c0000 880c0000 00200000 00200000 R E 00001000    -- b07
LOAD    00291000 c02c0000 882c0000 00280000 00280000 R E 00001000    -- b08
LOAD    00511000 c0540000 88540000 00033a2c 00033a2c RWE 00001000    -- b09
LOAD    00545000 c0574000 88574000 000b0a2c 000b0a2c R E 00001000    -- b10
LOAD    005f6000 c0630000 88630000 000f78b4 000f78b4 R E 00001000    -- b11
LOAD    006ee000 c0728000 88728000 00df81d0 00df81d0 R E 00001000    -- b12
LOAD    014e7000 c1540000 89540000 00062fe0 00062fe0 RW  00001000    -- b13
LOAD    0154a000 c15c0000 895c0000 004fbb93 004fbb93 R   00001000    -- b14
LOAD    01a46000 c1abd000 89abd000 00208a83 00208a83 RW  00001000    -- b15
DYNAMIC 01c47284 c1cbe284 89cbe284 00000078 00000078 RW  00000004    -- b16
LOAD    01c4f000 c1cc6000 89cc6000 00000000 000ddc64 RW  00001000    -- 
LOAD    01c50000 c1da4000 89da4000 00000000 010b9000 RW  00001000    -- 
LOAD    01c4f000 c2e5d000 8ae5d000 00013e00 00013e00 RW  00001000    -- b19
LOAD    01c63000 c2e71000 8ae71000 00079648 00079648 R   00001000    -- b20 .. zlib
LOAD    01cdd000 c2eeb000 8aeeb000 00947000 00947000 R   00001000    -- b21 .. q6zip
LOAD    02625000 c3833000 8b833000 00013000 00013000 RW  00001000    -- b22 .. delta
LOAD    02639000 c3847000 8b847000 0008e000 0008e000 RWE 00001000    -- b23
LOAD    026c8000 c38d6000 8b8d6000 0006ecb4 0006ecb4 RW  00001000    -- b24
LOAD    02737000 c3945000 8b945000 00000000 01bbb000 RW  00001000    --
```

Other things to note:

- modem.mdt == modem.b00 + modem.b01
- modem.b01 contains sha256 hashes of all other non empty sections. And a signature and certificates.
- modem.b20 can be decompressed using zlib.decompress
- modem.b21 and modem.b22 use compression methods designed by qualcomm. Named q6zip and deltacompress respectivly.

I will soon post decompression tools for the delta and q6zip sections on my github account.
EDIT: Soon was 6 years later, now on [github](https://github.com/nlitsme/qualcomm-q6zip)

The qualcomm hexagon documentation can be found [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/hexagon-dsp-sdk/tools), free registration required. The instruction set is described in [Hexagon V62 Programmer's Reference Manual](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/hexagon/hexagon-v62-programmers-reference-manual.pdf).

See also the [README.md](https://github.com/gsmk/hexagon/blob/master/README.md) from https://github.com/gsmk/hexagon.

Comment: That did the trick. IDA does assemble the file now. Would you happen to know where I could find documentation of the Hexagon instruction set, or examples?

Comment: Where can I find those: "decompression tools for the **delta** and **q6zip**"?

Answer (score 2):

for decompressing RO or RW sections,
I recommend using the utilities from the sources.
q6zip_ro_uncompress.py or rw_decompress_file.py

universal method of unpacking - doesn't exist,
even on one chipset, the algorithm, like add q6zip, or RO dictionary size can change.
so, better has the same version of sources.

I can't give a more accurate answer,
because while I was olny decompress the few RO section,
RW - unpacked with errors.

unpack is better on Linux. and sources need recompile.

I also recommend trying to swith the device into download mode, and just dump the memory. although I'm not sure that there will be all the unpacked blocks, but worth a try.

I now have a similar problem with MDM9230, TCL(alcatel) Y900NB, I don't even know what version of dlpager is used (( and  I can't unpack it too.
(i haven't HW, I just work with SW)

in principle, all the above just flooding, I only want to ask Willem Hengeveld, maybe he will tell something more, but need rep 50 for comment, so need answer ))

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but where can we find those scripts/resources?

Comment: as I wrote above, all scripts in the BB  source code distributed by QCOM. Of course, there are not only scripts, but also * .c files as well. 
The problem is when there are none QCOM support.
what are your result, except that were missed?

Comment: To be honest, I was looking for a concrete link or pointer to whan should/can an individual do to get those resources from QCOM, if that's relevant.

Comment: it's horrible. I see xda-dev. I haven't any  to say.

Comment: @0xC0000022L users are limited by the *number* (8) of links they can post in a single comment/answer, so there shouldn't be a problem for newcomers to post a link to a resource.

Comment: @NirIzr Fair enough